# Maven clean not working

Tags: java, maven

I've created a maven project in eclipse. Configured the stuff. But, when I click on Maven      clean, its not showing anything ( I mean the process in console). I guess its not instantiating maven. Am I missing anything?

```
My Pom.xml is like this 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MavenProject</groupId>
<artifactId>Maven</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>`enter code here`
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Regards
Nizam

Comment: Yes. You are missing giving us something to go on. Do you get any errors or messages that could guide us?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors or anything. The console just keeps clean. I've added my pom.xml. Please check.

Comment: Can you invokde `mvn clean` manually from command line instead?

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess that this maven clean is actually just invoking the regular Eclipse project clean to get a speed boost, but I didn't implement the Maven plugin so I can't know for sure.

Comment: aaa@uk:~$ mvn clean /home/anand/R\&D/Maven/
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/anand). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
This is the error which I'm getting

Comment: You need to run `mvn` in the directory where you code lives. The error is pretty self explanatory `there is no POM in this directory`. `cd` into `/home/anand/R\&D/Maven/` and type `mvn clean`

Comment: Yes. Its working in command prompt. Sorry that was the mistake. But, why its still not running in Eclipse?

Comment: Take look at Eclipse logs and Eclipse Maven configuration.

Comment: Which console are you viewing ? Whats the name of the console ?

Comment: It _might_ be a logging problem. Do you have a `log4j.properties` ore equivalent file? Also, you could try _Right Click_ on `pom.xml` -> _Run As_ -> _Maven clean_.

Answer (score 0):

There are possible to open more than one console at a time so you may be viewing wrong one so please check your viewing right console or not. you can jump one console to another by selecting console